# How to know if a .war file is bundled with Maven?

Tags: maven, jar, war

There are two questions:

1) Is there a way to "bundle" Maven with a .war file, in the sense that even if Maven is not installed on the machine, deploying the .war file will start Maven?

2) If the answer to 1) is yes, how do I know by looking at WEB-INF/lib of the .war file whether that .war is "bundled" with Maven or not? Which .jar files should I look for that will tell me that this .war file comes "bundled" with Maven?

I tried Googling this, all I found was ways to ***use*** Maven to bundle other libraries into my .jar file, which does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no easy way to tell if Maven will be installed and run just by deploying a war. That's a resembling case to the classic "Halt Problem".

Of corse, you could open the war and see if the WEB-INF/lib directory contains a bunch of `maven-*.jar` libraries (outstanding the basic `maven-core-*.jar` among them), but that wouldn't mean necessarily that they would end being installed and run.

Moreover, not finding any of these libraries into the war wouldn't mean either that Maven is not bundled into, because it could be compressed into a single file named XXX-YYY and then compressed as a static resource into a jar, and then compressed again into the war. And, if you are investigating about an IDE packaging, I'm afraid this is quite probable.

The war could even download Maven from an update site (the Maven homepage itself) at run time.

Acording to the halt problem conclussion, the only sure way you could check if Maven is bundled into a war is deploying it and observing its behaviour after being run.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is there a way to "bundle" Maven with a .war file, in the sense
>   that even if Maven is not installed on the machine, deploying the .war
>   file will start Maven?

A war file is a web application archive.
It contains a web application that is designed to be deployed on a Servlet container.
Adding an standalone application as Maven in is really counter intuitive.

Besides, deploying a war and starting Maven are not traditionally coupled tasks.  You build a WAR with Maven but you don't run the built war with Maven. You run it on a server.

> 2) ... how do I know by looking at WEB-INF/lib
>   of the .war file whether that .war is "bundled" with Maven or not?
>   Which .jar files should I look for that will tell me that this .war
>   file comes "bundled" with Maven?

In a war, but also a jar and an ear, you should find a `META-INF` folder that contains meta data about the Java archive.
Inside it you should find the `MANIFEST.MF` file that contains multiple information which the `Created-By` property.

With a Maven 3 build, you should find a reference to Maven if the built was performed with Maven.
For example for an archive created with Maven 3.3.9, you would have :

```
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
```

To get more information about `MANIFEST.MF`, I encourage you to read the [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) tutorial of the Oracle documentation .

Comment: I am asking for an application that might be kind of like an IDE that uses Maven to build other projects developed on it.

Comment: With source code, the pom.xml presence is enough to consider whether the project is powered by maven.

Comment: Suppose I have a .war file which will be used to develop projects and this war is deployed on a machine that does not have Maven installed. This war application will use some source files to build a .jar file. Now, if the .war file comes with a maven-core-x.x.x.jar in its WEB-INF/lib folder and suppose there is a pom.xml file in the project made using the war application. My question is that because of the maven-core-x.x.x.jar file in the .war file, will the .war file by itself install Maven on the machine to build the project developed using the war application?